# More energy gained from the same force over the same distance

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy

[image]

When F is applied both m have acceleration F/2m to the right whilst also having an acceleration  towards each other. This leads to a kinetic energy gained from the force to the right and the force towards each mass.

If these masses were just connected in series the acceleration from the same force F would be F/2m this leads to a kinetic energy gained only from the force to the right.

The first scenario appears to lead  to more kinetic energy gained from the same force F acting over the same distance.

Where am I going wrong in my thought process here?

Comment: This site is full of people who just down vote without explanation and it’s becoming laughable at this point

Comment: are mass connected by a wire (or a rigid massless connection; should be the same) and is the force applied to a point of this connection?

Answer (score 2):

The kinetic energy gained by the masses depends on the distance $d$ through which the force $F$ moves.

In time $t$ the centre of mass of the system moves by distance $d(t)=\frac {Ft^2}{4m}$. If the angle between the masses is fixed then $F$ moves through the same distance $d(t)$ in time $t$ and so does work $Fd(t)=\frac {F^2t^2}{4m}$ on the system. The kinetic energy of the system after time $t$ is therefore $\frac {F^2t^2}{4m}$, which as expected corresponds to a speed $v=\frac {Ft} {2m}$ for each mass.

However, if the masses move towards each another then the COM is moving backwards relative to the middle of the rope joining the masses (the point where the force $F$ is applied). In time $t$ the COM must move a distance $d(t)=\frac {Ft^2}{4m}$, so the force $F$ must move through a distance $d'(t)$ that is greater than $d(t)$. Therefore the work done on the system by the force $F$, which is now $Fd'(t)$, is greater than $Fd(t)$. It is this additional work done by $F$ that accounts for the extra kinetic energy that the masses gain as they move towards each other.

Comment: The centre of mass moving backward does not necessarily mean where the force is being applied is moving backwards. The force acts in the middle of the rope. For example if the force works over 1 meter in both cases that 1 meter is defined by the distance between the middle of rope initially and finally.

Comment: @Blue5000 The COM is moving backwards *relative to* the middle of the rope, and the COM must move a distance $d(t)=\frac {Ft^2}{4m}$ in time $t$, so the middle of the rope moves a distance *greater than* $d(t)$ in time $t$.

Comment: The length between the masses and the centre of the rope remains constant therefore the centre of the rope accelerates at the same rate as the masses in both cases so it moves the same distance over the same time in both cases.

Comment: In the equation for work I thought S represents the distance the force moves over not the distance the centre of mass moves over

Comment: @Blue5000:  Think about it this way: suppose the center of the rope was fixed.  If the masses were set in motion with the same tangential velocity towards each other, so that the rope remained taut, the center of mass would move away to the left, away from the center of the rope.

Comment: You're saying in the second case theat the force must move through a greater distance. Suppose, as OP has asked, one moves the force F through the same distance in both cases. The COM must move the same distance in both cases. Won't the masses still move toward each other in the second case?

Comment: @Not_Einstein Since $F$ is constant the COM must accelerate at a constant rate $\frac F {2m}$, so the distance moved by the COM in time $t$ is always $d(t) = \frac {Ft^2}{4m}$. The midpoint of the rope cannot also move through the same distance in both cases - the geometry of the situation tells us that the midpoint of the rope moves through a greater distance that $d(t)$ if the masses move towards one another.

Comment: @Blue5000 "The length between the masses and the centre of the rope remains constant" - yes, but the projection of this length in the direction of $F$ changes over time if the masses move towards each other. "... therefore the centre of the rope accelerates at the same rate as the masses in both cases" - this is where you are mistaken.

Comment: @gandalf61 I'm slowly coming around to following you're explanation, which is well done. But just to eliminate all doubt... you're saying the force F must move through a greater distance, d', if the masses move toward each other. But how far the force moves could be under our control and it can intentionally be moved through the smaller distance d, thus doing the same amount of work as in the first case. Are you implying then that the masses would not move toward each other?

Comment: @Not_Einstein Yes. We know the COM must move a distance $d(t)$ in time $t$. If we constrain the middle of the rope so that it also moves a distance $d(t)$ in time $t$ then the distance between the COM and the middle of the rope is constant, in which case the masses cannot move towards each other.

Answer (score 0):

"When F is applied both m have acceleration F/2m to the right" is where you are going wrong.

The acceleration is less than that.

Comment: The two masses and the connecting rods (assumed massless) move as if they were a single particle of mass 2m subject to the external force so the acceleration is F/2m. Why do you think it is not so?